# Book: suicidal girl is saved by a dragon in human form, dragon community faces internal strife

Tags: story-identification, books, dragons

Read this book several years ago for free on my Kindle.

It began with a girl's attempted suicide interrupted by a man. I believe he heals her?

We later find out he is a dragon. He lives with several others who are also dragons. He eventually tells her about them.

There is contention between the dragon people about her being brought into the fold. There is internal strife in the dragon community.

It ended like there would be subsequent books.

Comment: Did there happen to be clocks involved in this story?

Comment: I do not recall, I believe the girl worked in a hospital